# How to re-set the width and height of the cropping box in jwindowcrop?

Tags: javascript, image

I have this function which initializes jwindowcrop based on the predefined height and width

```
$('img#imgcrop_'+picSize+'_form_'+id).jWindowCrop({
    targetWidth: 400,
    targetHeight: 300,
    loadingText: 'Loading image...',
//and so on
```

However, I need to provide a feature to allow use to choose from "landscape" or "portrait" orientation and so I need to re-set the width and height to 300w and 400h. How can I possibly do this without re-initializing jwindowcrop?

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have the original reference to it and provided you know, for example, the element to which the jWindowCrop is bound, you can get a reference as follows:

```
var jwc = $(selector).getjWindowCrop();
```

From there on you can easily modify any of the set options.

```
jwc.options.zoomSteps = 2
```

However from [the basic documentation](https://github.com/tybro0103/jWindowCrop#options) it seems that there are no setters for `targetWidth` and `targetHeight` so you'll need to manually control it as shown below.

```
var newHeight = 200;
jwc.$frame.height(newHeight);
jwc.options.targetHeight = newHeight;
```

Additional complications may exist, but this is the basic gist of it.